# AngularJS and D3.js V4, d3.json issue

Tags: angularjs, json, d3.js

I am trying to integrate my d3.js code with AngularJS and I am having an issue with the d3.json function

```
    var OrgChartApp = angular.module('OrgChartApp', []);

//APP CONTROLLER
OrgChartApp.controller('OrgChartCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

  var i = 0,
      stratify,
      data,
      tree;                                                                                                                

  data = d3.json("orgChartDataSMALL.json",function(error, data){

    if(error) throw error;
    $scope.$apply(function(){//Setting up data for stratification by indicating what will be the parent and children nodes
      console.log('applying');
      stratify = d3.stratify()
                    .id(function(d) {return d.FullName;})//Position
                    .parentId(function(d) {return d.Manager;});//Manager's position

      $scope.root = stratify(data); //Transforming linear data into hierarchical data

      //Data needs slight remapping before feeding it into tree layout.
      $scope.root.each(function(d) {

        d.name = d.id; //transferring name to a name variable
        d.id = i; //Assigning numerical Ids
        i++;
        /*Calculating the numbers of employe under managers*/ 
       d.headcount = getDescendants(d); 
      }); 

    });

  });  

  console.log($scope.root);//THIS COMES BACK AS UNDEFINED

  //This function allows to figure out, how many employee are under a manager.
  function getDescendants(node) {
          if(!node.children && !node._children) {
              return 0;
          }
          var total = 0;

          if(node.children){
              node.children.forEach(function(d) {
              total += 1+getDescendants(d);
            })
          }else if(node._children){
              node._children.forEach(function(d) {
              total += 1+getDescendants(d); 
            })
          }

          return total;
      }                                     

});
```

The console.log under the d3.json comes back as undefined and when I pass the data to my directive I get the same.
I feel like there is a simple answer but I can't figure it out...

```
<div ng-App='OrgChartApp' ng-controller="OrgChartCtrl">
    <!-- Here's where our visualization will go -->
    <ochart-visualization root="root"></ochart-visualization>
</div>
```

And here is the top part of my directive:

```
//APP DIRECTIVES
OrgChartApp.directive('ochartVisualization',function($window, $document){

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      root:  '='
    },
    link: function ( scope, element ) {
```

I tried to inspire myself by http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/9496218

Comment: `d3.json` is async, your `console.log($scope.root);` is outside the function callback and will execute before the callback fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting a watch on the root variable in my directive i was able to make it work, as mark pointed out the async nature of the function made it so the console.log was undefined. Setting up a $watch in the directive and only acting when root was not undefined did the trick!